# Typo3 Fluid: add link to homepage

Tags: templates, typo3, fluid

I have some content elements created with the DCE extension.
In one of the templates, I loop through some products and I want to insert links like:

```
<a href="http://www.sitedomain.com/{product.alias}">{product.name}</a>
```

How can I do this without writing my own view helper?
Is it possible to access baseURL inside Fluid templates?

Thanks!

Comment: Try EXT:vhs - https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Site/UrlViewHelper.html

Comment: you can use a fluid viewhelper to read the typoscript setup: http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/CObject.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I left the links like:

```
<a href="/{product.alias}">{product.name}</a>
```

And set in typoscript config:

```
absRefPrefix = http://www.sitedomain.com
```

This was needed only for a specific request, for a certain typeNum, so the normal typo3 content pages are not affected.